# Deference between and operator and comma operator in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When i try to execute this command it fails to execute.

```
select * from emp order by deptno asc and job desc;
```

But when i execute the following command it works fine .

```
select * from emp order by deptno asc,job desc;
```

Can anyone explain me why 'and' doesn't work and ',' works ?

Comment: Go through th link http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm

Comment: I still couldn't get what is the reason for , working and and not working.

Comment: The comma in that context is *not* an operator. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `and` is a logical operator, it checks to see if something = something `and` something-else = something-else. `and` will return true or false, for example.

A comma simply sits between multiple things in the statement. There is nothing to return true or false about when ordering (`asc` or `desc`) your results - it simply orders them and that's that.

Comment: is , an operator ? If so then what is its name ?

Comment: Hmm, that's a tricky one to answer, and I'm definitely no expert. I'd personally say no, but I think Aldoras' comment above gives an excellent explanation. According to Oracle: "An operator manipulates individual data items and returns a result." - I don't see a comma manipulating data

Answer (score 3):

The [`order by` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) is an expression list:

> You can specify multiple expressions in the *`order_by_clause`*. Oracle Database first sorts rows based on their values for the first expression. Rows with the same value for the first expression are then sorted based on their values for the second expression, and so on.

And an [expression list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions015.htm) is comma-separated. I would call the comma a separator rather than an operator.

`AND` is a logical operator as already noted by others. Something to consider along with what has been said about that is that `AND` doesn't imply any order of evaluation, just that both conditions must be true.

In English rather than SQL there would be no difference between 'order by x and y' and 'order by y and x`. As a human you might *assume* what is meant, and that they are different; but a computer (or at least an SQL parser) would follow different rules of interpretation.

To be explicit in English you might say 'order by x **then** y' because *then* does imply an order of evaluation that *and* does not. SQL does not understand `THEN` in this context either though. The `order by` clause, as the docs state, adds an evaluation order to its interpretation of the expression list.

Comment: In theory, if Oracle SQL supported booleans, one might say "order by is_customer and is_live asc, created_at desc" I guess

Comment: @DavidAldridge - assuming you defined either true or false as 'higher' than the other; but you still only have one expression - is it really different from Lalit's case expression example? The `and` still isn't substituting for a comma? (Though maybe that wasn't your point... just that you could then make something that *looked* like what the OP attempted...)

Comment: no that wasn't my point :) Just that in an alternate universe one might get an AND in an order by.

Answer (score 2):

`AND` Is used to filter records based on more than one condition.

`ORDER BY` Is used to sort records the result-set by one or more columns.

The main difference, and the reason why your first line is not working, is  that `order by columnName` is **NOT** a condition and therefore you can't join them with `AND`.

Here is a good explanation with some examples-
[W3Schools-Order_By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: is , an operator ? If so then what is its name ?

Comment: I would say it is an operator. Comma `,` is used to separate two or more arguments of the previous keywords. For example `select * from Table1, Table2, Table3` or `SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country ASC, CustomerName DESC;` Obviously u cant use that with `AND` because it needs exactly 2 logical conditions.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain me why 'and' doesn't work and ',' works ?

Because `ORDER BY` can have a **list** of **columns, alias, reference by position, functions or expressions**. And when I say **list**, it is just like SELECT list or IN list generated by comma separated values. That is the basic **syntax**.

Basically, `,` or **comma** is a **separator** in the list. **AND** is a **condition**, which could be a part of the **expression** in the `ORDER BY` **list**, but not as a separator in itself.

```
OR  - separator
AND - condition
```

From documentation about [SQL Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions001.htm#SQLRF52101),

> The purpose of AND condition is conjunction.

For example,

```
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN empno = 1234 
    AND deptno =10 -- AND is a part of the expression
       THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END, -- comma as separator in the ORDER BY list
id DESC
```